# How To Retrieve password From HTML Form and Then Print It

Tags: php, html, forms

Well, I am working on a new project which has a login page. The Error: I am unable to retrieve password from the form using $_POST method.
The Form Code:

```
<form action="loginsub.php" method="post">
<input type="password" name="pass" id="pass"/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Go!"/>
</form>
```

The Code in loginsub.php

```
<? echo $_POST['pass']; ?>
```

I have also tried this method using text in place of password and it works. But what is the problem with the password? When I fill in the form and then submit it, the next page displays nothing!

Okay, Now, It's working! Thank you all, The Real Problem was: I want to take in password from a login form and then using mysql_query (php) want to find out if the username and password combination is there or not. If I am not wrong, the code for it is:

```
require_once('dbconfig.php');
$username = $_POST['username'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
$dbc = mysql_connect($dbserver,$dbuser,$dbpassword);
mysql_select_db('hello');
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password = PASSWORD('$pass')";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($row == 1)
{ echo "User Name and Password are Correct"; }
else
{ echo "Error! Username and Password is Wrong!"; }
```

Is the code right? When I execute it, enter correct username and password (which exists in the database, I get the InCorrect Message, but again when I enter wrong username and password, I still get InCorrect message. Why?

Comment: This should work just fine, does your application contain any other code? Does it display anything at all? Do you have short tags enabled?

Comment: are you sure? what happens if you do an ISSET($_POST['pass']);

Comment: try with <?php echo $_POST['pass']; ?>

Comment: Your not redirecting or something like that, so the form is empty before you post (just checking)?

Comment: Baszz wants to know if you're just going to the link that is your page, or submitting a form that redirects there - just clarifying. Also, it's a good idea to start your tags like this `<?php` instead of `<?` - it's a standard.

Comment: @tekknolagi is <?--?> different from <?php---?> ? Well, all the other php functions are working fine using <?--?>.

Comment: `<?` is a worse practice -> it's an established standard to use `<?php` and some interpreters will break

Answer (score 1):

I take you don't really want to print the password in your application? Anyway, it should be in your `$_POST` array - could you paste the output of putting

```
var_dump( $_POST );
```

in the page your submitting to?

Comment: sorry, I am not able understand what you're tryin' to say? [ I am a newbie ]

Comment: he's telling you to show all the variables in the array $_POST so we can see what's there